# Python range(%d) % sides

Tags: python, python-2.7, range

I am trying to make a program, that uses the turtle module using Python 2.7.5+.
The user can input a integer so I want to use that number as a argument for range()

Here is my code so far:

```
import turtle
import time
sides = int(raw_input("Enter the amount of sides you want!"))
angle = float(360 / sides)
length = int(raw_input("Enter the length of each side!"))
#Starts turtle drawer
turtle = turtle.Turtle()
def turtleDrawer():
    for i in range (%d) : % (sides)
        turtle.fd(%d) % (length) 
        turtle.rt(%d) % (angle)
ws = turtle.Screen()
turtleDrawer()
time.sleep(10)
```

When this code is executed, it gives me a syntax error, highlighting the `%` sign in the brackets.

Comment: You should point to some evidence of research (code, links to what you've tried etc.. and again, show us some form of code to work with).

Comment: I want the user to be able to choose a shape by inputting values. I want the sides to be the range() and the other numbers to controll the movement of the turtle, but when this code is executed, it gives me a syntax error, highlighting the % sign in the brackets. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help with my post. :)

Comment: `for i in range (%d) : % (sides)` is rubbish. You want `for i in range(sides):`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for i in range (%d) : % (sides)` is invalid. This type of [formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) is used for strings, not for conditional statements.

You are looking for this statement:

```
for i in range(sides):
```